# Looping struct inside struct

Tags: go, struct

I am trying to save form data in graph database (dgraph ) for which I need to iterate another struct inside parent struct.

I have couple of struct with name `Tag` and `Question` and I have array with name `words`.

I have to fill the `Question`struct with `words` array as array `Tag` struct

This is what I am trying to do:

```
type Tag struct {
    Name string
    Count string
}

type Question struct {
    Title string
    Tags []Tag
}

words := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four"}

tagsList := []Tag
for i=0;i<len(words);i++ {
    tagsList = append(tagsList, words[i])
}

q := Question {
    Title: "Kickstart Business with Corporate Leadership",
    Tags: tagsList,
}
```

I am getting error: "type []Tag is not an expression"

I need help in putting "tallest" in "Question" struct value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To initialize a variable to an empty slice, you want `[]Tag{}`, not `[]Tag`. You can also range over the list of words which is a bit easier, and then you just need to construct your Tag from the word, e.g.

```
words := []string{"one", "two", "three", "four"}

tagsList := []Tag{}
for _, word := range words {
    tagsList = append(tagsList, Tag{Name: word})
}
```

Full [example on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/CfIa0S_QcrU)

Comment: Got it. Thanks for sharing knowledge (y)